# Variable ViewBag name in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically, I'm working on a project and I'm not sure how I can put a variable ViewBag name, which I want to do because all the following code is inside of a while loop.

```
List<SelectListItem> PermissionLevels = new List<SelectListItem>();
PermissionLevels.Add (new SelectListItem  {//skipping this section, not relevant
ViewBag.@ContactName = PermissionLevels;
```

and then in the view I have inside of a foreach loop:

```
@Html.DropDownList(_CurrentPermissions.Name)
```

(Yes, _CurrentPermissions is the correct name where it is located.)

What I'm really trying to do here is get @ContactName to be a variable but I'm not sure how to do it, this was my best guess and I can't seem to find any way to do it

Comment: In razor: `@var PermissionLevels = ViewBag.ContactName;` . I would remove the `@` at the C# side too, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want to include in your `ViewBag` is a `Dictionary` of `List<SelectListItem>` indexed by name?

```
Dictionary<string, List<SelectListItem>> Permissions = 
  new Dictionary<string, List<SelectListItem>>();

List<SelectListItem> PermissionLevels = new List<SelectListItem>();

Permissions[ContactName] = new SelectListItem( ... ) // Repeat for each name

ViewBag.Permissions = Permissions;
```

and then in the view inside of a foreach loop:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Permissions[_CurrentPermissions.Name])
```

Don't forget to check that the key exists before indexing into the dictionary.  You also might look into the `SelectList` class which is a collection of `SelectListItems` specifically designed to display in an `HTML.DropDownList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  Fear not!  There's a better way to handle this problem.

If you need a `List` of objects returned to your view, just store the list in the `ViewBag` or store it as a property on the model.

Since it sounds like you're building a list of permissions per user, it might look *something* like this:

```
var permissionsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<SelectListItem>>();

foreach (var user in users) {
    var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem() {
        //Do your stuff!
    });

    permissionsDictionary.Add(user.Name, listItems);
}

model.Permissions = permissionsDictionary;
```